# Do we need both equipment and ground-equipment tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tagging, retagging

- [equipment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) **30** questions

> The equipment tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

- [ground-equipment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-equipment) **2** questions

> The ground-equipment tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

**Question:** Do we need both equipment and ground-equipment tags?

The equipment tag seems well-used and generally not used for ground equipment except for

- [Are cherrie-pickers a new thing in spaceflight?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/54659/12102) (I added both, then wrote this question)
- [Why was 65 volts used for ground support equipment?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43378/12102) (lacks ground-equipment)

If we want to support a ground-equipment tag, then we'll need to add it to all the questions about ground equipment.

If not, should it be deleted because it is not actually serving any useful purpose nor being used?

Comment: I support removing `ground-support`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think merging and synonymizing [ground-equipment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ground-equipment) into [equipment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equipment) is a good idea.

Comment: Sounds good to me.